# Understanding proof of proposition on compact spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Definition:A family of $\{F_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in\Omega}$ of closed subsets of a set $X$ is said to have the finite intersection property if $\cap_{\alpha\in \mathcal{B}}F_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$ for all finite $\mathcal{B}\subset\Omega$.

> Proposition: A topological space $X$ is compact if and only if for all family $\{F_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in\Omega}$ of closed sets with finite intersection property, $\cap_{\alpha\in \Omega}F_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$

> Proof:Let $U_\alpha=(F_\alpha)^c$, then $\cap_{\alpha\in \Omega}F_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset \iff \cup_{\alpha\in \omega}U_\alpha \neq X$, and $\{F_\alpha\}$ has the finite intersection property if and only if no finite subfamily of $\{U_\alpha\}$ covers X. The result follows.

I am really confused: 1st, shouldn't we suppose $\{F_\alpha\}$ have the F.I.P. and $\cap_{\alpha\in \Omega}F_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$ then there exists a finite subfamily of $\{U_\alpha\}$ that covers $X$? 2nd How does no finite subfamily of some family of open sets that do not cover $X$ implies the space is compact, is this some sort of contrapositive proof that I am not seeing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof presented is very brief. Here is how the proof of compactness goes: Let $(U_{\alpha})$ be any open cover of $X$ and let $F_{\alpha}=U_{\alpha}^{c}$. This gives a family of closed sets and $\cap_{\alpha} F_{\alpha}=\emptyset$. So there is a finite subcollection of $F_{\alpha}$'s whose intersection is empty. The union of the coresponding $U_{\alpha}$'s is the whole space $X$. We have proved that every open cover of $X$ has  finite subcover.

Comment: Hi, when I look back at this the proof you showed is indeed correct but I have another question, why do we need the F.I.P. and the arbitrary intersection to be none empty?